# PowerShell regular expression struggles

Tags: powershell

This is my first post, I tend to be able to find what I need by reading and searching other posts, but this one has me defeated.  I am trying to use a regular expression in Powershell to look for data in a text file.

Sample text file:(There are spaces in the sample text file until the end of that line)

```
 Impression            CONCLUSION:                                                                     
 Impression                        
            
 Impression            CONCLUSION:                                                                     
 Impression            SomeData

 Impression            CONCLUSION:                                                                     
 Impression            SomeOtherData

 Impression            CONCLUSION:                                                                     
 Impression
```

I am looking to find where the second line is blank after the line with conclusion.

This was the base of my simple attempt:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Log\Conclusion.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "CONCLUSION:\s*\r\n\s*Impression\s*\r\n\s*Impression" -Context 1, 1
```

I found that Anything with \r\n would not return any results.  I tried both \r and \n on their own, I attempted to Get content as Raw, but that just outputs the entire file again.  Help is appreciated, thank you.

**Update:** Thanks for everyone's responses, I should have specificed I was attempting to find lines after conclusion that were empty.  I ended up getting a count to work for starters with using Get-Content -Raw.  My sample data changed slightly to add another blank line with the word impression:
Name/Location
Impression            CONCLUSION:
Impression
Impression

This code was able to get me a count:(pulled/modified from another forum post, I do not take credit for coming up with this)

$search_string = "\s*CONCLUSION:\s*\r\n\s*Impression\s*\r\n\s*Impression\s*\r\n\s*Impression\s*\r\n"
$file_path = "C:\temp\Log\Conclusion.txt"
$string = (Get-Content -raw -Path $file_path | Select-String $search_string -AllMatches | % { $_.matches}).count

I am still working on a way to print some more data that would only work when not using Raw, I had planned to use context to grab the line above conclusion, but since raw brings everything in one line, that does not work.  Thanks again for the help, if anyone has any more tips about being able to use \r\n and not using Raw, please let me know.

Comment: When you say, "...second line is blank after the line with conclusion...", do you mean blank *beneath*  the __`Conclusion:`__ "header" in the previous line?

Comment: What do you mean by "...There are spaces in the sample text file until the end of that line..."? Are you saying that lines are padded to a fixed witdth?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how well this will work with powershell, but give this a shot:
`(*CRLF)CONCLUSION:\sImpression\s\s`

https://regex101.com/r/d6Pm2k/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ugly brute force attack:

```
$blankRows = @()
$targetRows = @()
$rowNum = 0
$foundRows = @()

$myFile = Get-Content $thisFile

Foreach($thisRow in $myFile){
    $rowNum++
    if($thisRow -eq "Impression"){$blankRows += $rowNum}
    if ($thisRow -match 'CONCLUSION'){$targetRows += $rowNum}
}

Foreach($blrw in $blankRows){
    if ($targetRows -contains ($blrw-1)){$foundRows += $blrw}

}

$foundRows
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what you wnat to capture, the completely blank lines or the ones with `Impression` and no data following.

But per the documentaation, [Get-Contnet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1):

- For files, the content is read one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each of which represents a line of content.

SO the `<newline>` characters are "consumed" as the element seperators of a string array.
Try:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Log\Conclusion.txt" | gm
(Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Log\Conclusion.txt").Count
```

so you'll never match a `<newline>` with the code as written.

You can use the `-Raw` paramaeter to treat the file as one long string with `<newline>` characters or re-writing your logic for searching an array.

---

Also, the documentation for [Select-string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7#example-8--find-lines-before-and-after-a-match) show that it can take a file directly and process it line-by-line, with no need for `Get-Content`.

---

### UpDate

I'm still not sure what line you want to output, but here is a skeleton sample of what I *think* you're asking for. My assumptions are:

- The lines you're looking for are those with no text following "Impression" (Please clarify if this is literal or data)
- When a match is found, The previous line is captured for the output file.

```
$File = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\Log\Conclusion.txt"
$OutLines   = @()
$EmptyMatch = '^Impression\s*$'
$i = 0
ForEach ( $line in $File ) {
    If ( $line -match $EmptyMatch ) {
        $OutLines += $File[ $i - 1 ]
    }
    $i++
}
$OutLines | Set-Content 'c:\MyStuff\OutFile.txt'
Add
```

Comment: Thank you, this led me to what I needed to at least get a count of the instances it occurs in the file, but still attempting to find a way to print my results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
# Create some sample data file
@'
Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression SomeData

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression SomeOtherData

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression
'@ | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt' -Force
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt'
# Results
<#
Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression SomeData

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression SomeOtherData

Impression CONCLUSION:
Impression
#>

# Import the sample data file as a CSV, use the space as a Delimiter
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt' -Delimiter ' ' -Header Property, Value
# Results
<#
Property   Value        
--------   -----        
Impression CONCLUSION:  
Impression              
Impression CONCLUSION:  
Impression SomeData     
Impression CONCLUSION:  
Impression SomeOtherData
Impression CONCLUSION:  
Impression              
#>

# Filter by the Value property
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt' -Delimiter ' ' -Header Property, Value | 
Where-Object -Property Value -EQ $null
# Results
<#
Property   Value
--------   -----
Impression      
Impression  
#>

# Using Select-String and a RegEx 'Not Match'
Select-String -Path 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt' -Pattern '^((?!Impression [a-zA-Z]).)*$'
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:2:Impression
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:3:
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:6:
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:9:
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:11:Impression
#>

# Using Select-String and RegEx match
Select-String -Path 'D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt' -Pattern '^Impression\s*$'
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:2:Impression
D:\Temp\Imprestion.txt:11:Impression
#>
```

***Explanation:***

- ^ is the beginning of string anchor.
- $ is the end of string anchor.
- \s is the whitespace character class.
- is zero-or-more repetition of.